# How to convert string timestamp to UTC and local in dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to hadoop. I have to convert effective string timestamp to UTC and local in a pyspark dataframe. 
Dataframe has 3 billion rows. I'm using spark 2.4.0.
Input date format is like: "2019-09-10 00:00:16.92516 +2:00" I want to get rid of "+2:00" and it should be fast.

Comment: How do the docs say to do it?

Comment: I tried everything I found in the internet - no success. I think my problem is with the format +2:00. Sorry I'm new to spark.

Comment: I am also unfamiliar with pyspark. You just want to *truncate* the string and exclude the offset?

Comment: For local maybe ok but not for utc. Couldn’t get it to work with „to_timestamp“.